# Find all primes $p$ and $r$ such that $ pr+1+r^3=p^2 $

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I tried some small values, and I found that $p=7$ and $r=3$ was a solution.
I ve also find a way to factorise the equation:
$$ p(p-r)=(r+1)(r^2-r+1)$$
Since  we know that $ p > r+1 $ then $$p| (r^2\color{blue}{-}r+1) $$
That's all what i've found , thank you in advance fo your precious help !

Comment: People are very arrogant making a downvote here. If you have time to waste in a downvote, you can waste your time writting a comment about what should he improve, give him a time to improve and if he doesnt improve his question, you are free to downvote. He shows his effort and it is a valid question

Comment: For a very similar post, see [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2180688/find-all-pairs-of-prime-numbers-p-and-q-such-that-p2-p-1-q3). Perhaps it is also useful here.

Comment: Every post is different from anyone else. So the original poster does not deserve any downvote.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean $r^2\color{red}-r+1$ where you typed $r^2+r+1$?

Comment: Yup , i ll correct it rn

Comment: By SAGE, the elliptic curve $y^2-xy=x^3+1$ has rank $2$, and the following integral points: $(-1,0),(0,1),(1,2),(3,7),(5,14),(8,27),(64,545)$ and $(119,1359).$ If the results are reliable, then $r=3,p=7$ will be the only solution to your question.

Comment: @Luis Felipe. We may be good at maths. But at the end of the day we are all monkeys. wo wo wo wooooo

Answer (score 4):

As you've already noted,

$$p(p - r) = (r + 1)(r^2 - r + 1) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Also, there's a positive integer $k$ such that

$$p \mid (r^2 - r + 1) \; \; \to \; \; r^2 - r + 1 = kp \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Similar to how [Find all pairs of prime numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $\,p^2-p-1=q^3.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2180688/602049) that [Dietrich Burde](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83966/dietrich-burde)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4222384/find-all-primes-p-and-r-such-that-pr1r3-p2#comment8767593_4222384) suggested is solved, substitute \eqref{eq2A} into \eqref{eq1A} and divide both sides by $p$ to get

$$p - r = (r + 1)k \; \; \to \; \; p = (r + 1)k + r \; \; \to \; \; p = (k + 1)r + k \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Substituting this into \eqref{eq2A} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& r^2 - r + 1 = k((k + 1)r + k) \\
& r^2 - r + 1 = (k^2 + k)r + k^2 \\
& r^2 + (-k^2 - k - 1)r + (1 - k^2) = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

This is a quadratic equation in $r$, so the quadratic formula gives

$$r = \frac{k^2 + k + 1 \pm \sqrt{(-k^2 - k - 1)^2 - 4(1 - k^2)}}{2} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

For $r$ to be integral requires the discriminant (note I use $(-k^2 - k - 1)^2 = (-(k^2 + k + 1))^2 = (k^2 + k + 1)^2$ for convenience), i.e.,

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
d & = (k^2 + (k + 1))^2 - 4(1 - k^2) \\
& = k^4 + 2k^2(k + 1) + (k + 1)^2 - 4 + 4k^2 \\
& = k^4 + 2k^3 + 2k^2 + k^2 + 2k + 1 - 4 + 4k^2 \\
& = k^4 + 2k^3 + 7k^2 + 2k - 3
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

must be the square of an integer. Consider the values of $k$ for which

$$(k^2 + k + 2)^2 = k^4 + 2k^3 + 5k^2 + 4k + 4 \lt d \lt (k^2 + k + 3)^2 = k^4 + 2k^3 + 7k^2 + 6k + 9 \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

is true. With the first inequality, we get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
k^4 + 2k^3 + 5k^2 + 4k + 4 & \lt k^4 + 2k^3 + 7k^2 + 2k - 3 \iff \\
5k^2 + 4k + 4 & \lt 7k^2 + 2k - 3 \iff \\
-2k^2 + 2k & \lt -4 - 3 \iff \\
-2k(k - 1) & \lt -7
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

This is true for all $k \ge 3$. Note the second inequality in \eqref{eq7A} is true for all positive $k$. Thus, \eqref{eq7A} holds for all $k \ge 3$. This means $d$ is between two consecutive perfect squares and, thus, can't be a perfect square itself, so we must have $k \lt 3$.

With $k = 1$, \eqref{eq6A} gives $d = 9$, so \eqref{eq5A} gives $r = 0, 3$, with only $r = 3$ being valid. In \eqref{eq2A}, this gives $p = 7$, as you've already determined. Next, using in $k = 2$ in \eqref{eq6A} gives $d = 61$, which is not a perfect square.

This means there's only the one solution you've already found, i.e., $p = 7$ and $r = 3$.

Comment: $ d=(-k^2-k-1)-4(1-k^2) $ not $(k^2+k+1)^2-4(1-k^2) $ right?

Comment: @Maxwol In a quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, the discriminant is $d = b^2 - 4ac$. In this case, $a = 1$, $b = -k^2 - k - 1$ and $c = 1 - k^2$. Thus, we get $d = (-k^2 - k - 1)^2 - 4(1 - k^2)$. Since $(-y)^2 = y^2$, for convenience, I used $(-k^2 - k - 1)^2 = (-(k^2 + k + 1))^2 = (k^2 + k + 1)^2$.

Comment: And what s d please, and what s the purpose of the line after $ k>3 $ plz?

Comment: @Maxwol In $(5)$, I'm using $d$ as the part inside of the square root sign. For $r$ to be an integer, then $d$ must be a perfect square, i.e., a square of an integer. If I can show that $d$ is between the squares of $2$ consecutive integers, then it can't be a perfect square itself. The purpose of the line after $k \ge 3$ is to show that in those cases, my $(8)$ will be true, i.e., $d$ can't be perfect square, so there's no integer solutions for $r$ in $(5)$. As such, I only need to check the cases of $k = 1$ and $k = 2$, with only the first one giving a valid solution.

Comment: Could you just explain to me part (7) please?

Comment: @Maxwol From part $(7)$, I get the left & middle parts of $(8)$. In particular, from the left side of $(7)$, moving some terms around gives $5k^2 + 4k + 4 \lt 7k^2 + 2k - 3$. Adding $k^4 + 2k^3$ to both sides gives $k^4 + 2k^3 + 5k^2 + 4k + 4 \lt k^4 + 2k^3 + 7k^2 + 2k - 3 = d$. The middle & right parts of $(8)$ apply for all positive $k$, so they also apply for $k \ge 3$.

Comment: @Maxwol Thank you for your feedback.  I decided that my last part was not clearly explained, so I basically switched my $(8)$ and $(7)$ around and expanded my now $(8)$ with details similar to my earlier comment to you.  I hope this is now clearer to you. As for your second last comment, the first part of my now $(7)$ only applies for $k \ge 3$ since, for example with $k = 2$, the left side becomes $-2(2)(1) = -4$ which is greater than $-7$. As for why $-7$ & not $0$, that's because in the inequalities, the left one has $+4$ and the right one has $-3$, so moving $+4$ to the right gives $-7$.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer: I haven't proven it, but I made enough progress that I feel it is worth sharing.

---

You have

$$r(r^2+p)=p^2-1=(p-1)(p+1)$$

which implies that $r|p-1$ or $r|p+1$. Assume it is the first case: then $p=rk+1$ for some natural $k$. This gives us

$$0=r^2+\left(k-k^2\right) r-2 k+1$$

Solving this gives

$$r=\frac{1}{2} \left((k-1) k+\sqrt{k \left(k (k-1)^2+8\right)-4}\right)$$

(we can ignore the other root since it is always negative). Since this has to be an integer, we know

$$\frac{\sqrt{k \left(k (k-1)^2+8\right)-4}}{2}\in\mathbb{N}$$

At this point, you could finish the proof by showing that this relation is only satisfied by a finite number of $k$ and then doing something similar for $p=rk-1$.